# Has anyone tried to measure, in a PhoneGap application, installations that came from Facebook Ads?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Has anyone tried to measure, in a PhoneGap application, installations that came from Facebook Ads?
As far as I saw in the docs, it's just a method call: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads/#advanced

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID: YOUR_APP_ID]; 
[FBAppEvents activateApp];
```

But the Facebook plugin for PhoneGap does not implement this class `FBAppEvents`: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
Before I give a clone and start writing, I was wondering if anyone has done / seen something that would supply it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is already implemented.

"Activation events are automatically tracked for you in the plugin."
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect

Just install the plugin from the command line and try out if it works. I will do so now.

```
cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect --variable APP_ID="XXXXXXXXX" --variable APP_NAME="YYYYYYYY"
```

Also I needed to install the facebook library to achieve a successful build. I followed these steps:

https://github.com/sebastianzillessen/phonegap-facebook-plugin/commit/ce5f868780ebdab04ef4a4549d5cdde2855aa695